# How can I display one item from this array in the render?

Tags: reactjs

I do not know of a way to display these conditions in the render. Nothing is appearing or if I try .map then it gives me errors.

I've tried refactoring, but came up with the same scenario. I've tried assigning the sampleInfo items to a new array but still can't figure out how to display just 1 item from that array in the render.

```
sampleInfo = [
    {
second: 1,
ml: '19ml',
animal: 'Thing1',
weight: '4kg',
capacity: '20ml'
    },

    {
second: 2,
ml: '38ml',
animal: 'Thing2',
weight: '7kg',
capacity: '35ml'
    },

    {
second: 3,
ml: '57ml',
animal: 'Thing3',
weight: '12kg',
capacity: '60ml'
    }

         ]
....Some functions here......

onSubmit(onetotwosec, morethantwosec) {

const {time} = this.state;

    this.setState((state, props) => ({
      scoreArray:state.scoreArray.concat(ms(state.time,{verbose: true})),
      time:0,
      submit:true

    }));

// let myNewanimalArray = state.animalArray.concat({morethantwosec});
// console.log(myNewanimalArray) 
      let filterAnimal = 0
    if((time >= 1000) && (time < 2000)) {
         filterAnimal = this.sampleInfo.filter((item) => {
            return item.second === 1;
        }).map((item) => {
            return item.animal
        });

         console.log(filterAnimal)
        }

        else if(time > 2000) {       
             filterAnimal = this.sampleInfo.filter((item) => {
                return item.second === 2;
            }).map((item) => {
                return item.animal
            });

             console.log(filterAnimal)

     } 
  }
render() {

    if((this.state.isOn) === true){

    return(

      <React.Fragment>

      <div>
        <h3>Timer:{ms(this.state.time,{verbose: true})}</h3>
      </div>
    <div>
      <button onMouseDown={this.onItemMouseDown} onMouseUp={this.onItemMouseUp}>start</button>   
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.scoreArray.map(function(item,i){

            return<li key={i}>{item}</li>
            })}
        </ul>
      </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    ) 

    } else if ((this.state.isOn) === false){  

      return(

        <React.Fragment>

      <div>

        <h3>Timer:{ms(this.state.time)}</h3>

      </div>

      <div>

      <button onMouseDown={this.onItemMouseDown} onMouseUp={this.onItemMouseUp}>Start</button><span></span> 

      <button onClick={this.resetTimer}>Reset</button>
<span></span>

      <button onClick={this.onSubmit}>Done!</button>

      </div>      

      <div>

        <ul>

        {this.state.scoreArray.map(function(item,i){

          return<li key={i}>{item}</li>

          })}

        </ul>
    //Here I've tried .map like above but can't figure out what to put!!!!
      </div>


      </React.Fragment>
```

I want the Done! button to display the matched animal from the sampleInfo array when the timer reaches a certain time. It should show each item as text such as 'Thing 1' if the timer is between 1 and 2 seconds etc. I can get it to display correctly using the console, but cannot for the life of me think of how to get it into the render. All of the functions are within one class.

Comment: What's the specific issue? If you know how to pick the item you want, then in render you pick the item and... render it.

Comment: So 
1. Why are you doing onMouseDown and onMouseUp with the same function call? Just do onClick. Unless you have a reason for doing it this way?
2. You are mutating state directly on you onSubmit. Big No-No. You need to update the state without mutating it. Something like map, filter, reduce or using a spread operator. I think you should take a look at the React docs and read over them. So 
1. Why are you doing onMouseDown and onMouseUp with the same function call? Just do onClick. Unless you have a reason for doing it this way?

Comment: 2. You are mutating state directly on you onSubmit. Big No-No. You need to update the state without mutating it. Something like map, filter, reduce or using a spread operator. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: To answer the first question from Dave, I know how to pick the item using console.log but I don't know how to render a single item from the provided array, such as displaying the text of 'Thing1'.

To answer Taylor:
1. It works correctly at the moment with mouse on and mouse off, I want it to be a 'hold the mouse down to run the timer' so I'm happy with the way it's running in that respect.
2. Can you provide a code example to avoid mutating the state directly? Which state do you mean in my code, animalArray or scoreArray?

Comment: I've updated the OnSubmit(). This now successfully displays the correct item in the console.log. My ultimate objective is to display the item in the render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it myself (with help from google and all the above - this has taken me 3 days to do such a simple thing), here's the onSubmit function updated:

```
 onSubmit() {
    this.setState((state) => ({
        scoreArray:state.scoreArray.concat(ms(state.time,{verbose: true})),
        time:0,
        submit:true

      }));

const {time} = this.state;


    var filterAnimal
    if((time >= 1000) && (time < 2000)) {
         filterAnimal = this.sampleInfo.filter((item) => {
            return item.second === 1;
        }).map((item) => {
            return item.animal
        }).toString()


         this.setState(prevState => ({
           animalArray:[filterAnimal,...prevState.animalArray ]})
           )

        }
```

And in the render:

```
{this.state.animalArray}
```

It works fine. If anyone can see a problem with this do comment.